# Is there auth.id in Go firebase cloud functions context?

Tags: node.js, firebase, go, authentication

I can’t find any reference to using context in golang cloud functions for firebase, however in node.js context there is auth info (info about the user, who requested the function on frontend). Can somebody explain to me, how can I get user.id in golang cloud functions?

Comment: You can pull metadata out of the context using the Fromcontext() in the cloud sdk: http://cloud.google.com/go/functions/metadata but auth.id isn't listed in it's output. Which type of cloud function are you using... Pub/sub, http, etc... ?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I’m aware about metadata, but I need specifically auth.id, I’m using http-trigger